# Print albanian characters in cmd using Java program

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, cmd, character-encoding

I have a string `"Përshëndetje botë!"` in a .java file and I am trying to print it using `System.out.println()`. The file is in ISO-8859-1 encoding.  In `cmd` I do

```
chcp 28591
```

to change the encoding to ISO-8859-1 (per [the list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Then I compile a .java file using

```
javac -encoding ISO-8859-1 C:\...\Hello.java
```

and run it using

```
java -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 packagename.Hello
```

In this case the `ë` are replaced with spaces.  I also tried

```
java -Dfile.encoding=ISO88591 packagename.Hello
```

and the `ë` were replaced with wrong foreign symbols.

How would I get it running?

Comment: Java uses UTF-16 by default, don't change the encoding. If you aren't seeing arabic characters then you need to install the operating system arabic language pack.

Comment: Are you sure your source file is actually in ISO-8859-1? Have you tried `-Dfile.encoding=ISO8859_1` (note underscore)? In any case, it's recommended to always have your source files in UTF-8.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, Sorry, I made a mistake in the title. Those are Albanian characters and ISO-8859-1 seems to be handling them fine when in IDE or Notepad++ at least... And I can't have a source file in UTF-8 because in that case the `ë` characters aren't displayed.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch, I edited the question. Those are Albanian.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I tried the underscore - results in spaces all over again(

Comment: What causes you to believe that your source code file is in ISO 8859-1 encoding? What text editor are you using? Does it appear correct in Windows Notepad.exe?

Comment: @lit, Because when the file is first opened in Idea Intellij, as UTF-8 the characters are damaged. When it's reloaded as ISO-8859-1 the charaters are all fine. The same works for Notepad++.

Comment: @lit, No, it's not correct in notepad.exe - the `ë`s are damaged..

Comment: What "wrong foreign symbols" exactly?  Would you please add them to your question?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Actual answer

Per the [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460131/print-albanian-characters-in-cmd-using-java-program/42487830?noredirect=1#comment72143813_42487830), the actual issue was that the font `cmd` was using didn't have the relevant symbols.

### Original post

I'm posting this as an answer because what I want to say is too long for comments :) .

First, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42460131/2877364) to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the printing code.  For example, if you could write a separate Java program that did nothing but print the message, that would be much easier to debug.  (Maybe `packagename.Hello` is such an example, but I can't tell.)

Second, please try the below, and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42460131/2877364) to include the results of each step.

1. Check the actual bytes in your source file to confirm its encoding, then edit your question to include that information.  You can use, e.g., [the FileFormat.info hex dumper](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hexdump.htm) (I am not affiliated with it).  For example, here is the output for your string, pasted into a UTF-8 text file:

   ```
   file name: foo.txt
   mime type: 

   0000-0010:  50 c3 ab 72-73 68 c3 ab-6e 64 65 74-6a 65 20 62  P..rsh.. ndetje.b
   0000-0017:  6f 74 c3 ab-21 0d 0a                             ot..!..
                     ^^ ^^                                        ^^
   ```

   Note, at the `^^` markers, that `ë` in UTF-8 is `0xc3 0xab`.

   By contrast, in ISO 8859-1 (aka "latin1" in vim), the same text is:

   ```
   file name: foo.txt
   mime type: 

   0000-0010:  50 eb 72 73-68 eb 6e 64-65 74 6a 65-20 62 6f 74  P.rsh.nd etje.bot
   0000-0014:  eb 21 0d 0a                                      .!..
               ^^                                               ^
   ```

   Note that `ë` is now `0xeb`.
2. Try running your command as `java packagename.Hello`, *without* any `-D` option.  In my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38876669/2877364) that you read, the `-D` option to `java` was not necessary.
3. Try code page `1250`, as in the [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38876453/2877364).

Comment: I figured out the cause of the problem - the Lucida font in cmd wasn't the active one, but thank you for answering, it was useful too.